# Where can we configure WCF parameters for WCF RIA services?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Wrt WCF RIA services. Where & How can we configure WCF parameters like message size, response timeout, transport protocol etc?

I am trying to WCF RIA services(PDC09 build) with Silverlight 3.0. I have tried searching but that didnt help much.

Any pointers will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know that it is not available in this PDC09 build and have to wait atleast until next public release of WCF RIA services